# How to find most frequent string value in a csv column and return it? (Python)

Tags: python, function, csv, return, frequency

(Not allowed to use pandas)

I am very new to python and struggling with this question. I am trying to create a function. I have a CSV file (called personal_info.csv) with a bunch of different columns (full_name, weight_b, height_c, etc). I am trying to loop through the column called height_c and return the most frequent number.
Some more info:
The range of said column is 0-10, though there is a possibility some numbers won't appear. The numbers are stored as strings (ex: '4') and I'm trying to return the value as a string as well. If there are any ties for the most frequent number, I just want to return the one that shows up first.

Here is some of the data from the csv file:

| file_name | weight_b | height_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john smith | 74 | 2 |
| rachel lamb | 32 | 5 |
| adam lee | 12 | 2 |
| mackenzie tre | 26 | 2 |
| abby wallace | 79 | 1 |
| karen brown | 46 | 7 |
| harry wright | 73 | 9 |
| madi bear | 53 | 4 |

So I'm trying to go through column height_c and find the most common value. (Which in this case would be 2), but the file is a lot longer than this.

(edited this to get rid of useless code)

Comment: Some example of data stored in your .csv file would be more useful, than bunch of code taken from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading the csv file into a Pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Then you can easily get the most common value in the 'heigt_m' column:

```py
df['heigt_m'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

EDIT:
Without using pandas, I would open and store all 'height_c' values in a list and then calculate the most common value:

```py
import csv

height_c = []
with open('file.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        height_c.append(row['height_c'])
        
most_frequent_height_c = max(set(height_c), key = height_c.count)

print(most_frequent_height_c)
2
```

Where the file.csv contains

```
file_name,weight_b,height_c
john smith,74,2
rachel lamb,32,5
adam lee,12,2
mackenzie tre,26,2
abby wallace,79,1
karen brown,46,7
harry wright,73,9
madi bear,53,4
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use pandas for this project :(